# GPO VBS Script does not run at startup

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016, vbscript, microsoft

I need to setup a GPO that execute a VBS script at Startup.
I already create a script and test it without GPO and works perfectly, but when I do gpupdate /force and restart computer, nothing changes.
Event viewer has no erros or warnings about Group Policy, in rsop.msc I have no errors too but Last Run collum is empty.
[rsop.msc result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3HMk.png)
[GPO rsume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yPl2.png)

EDIT: After update windows server I think I solved the system part running the GPO but now I'm getting error on GPO Scheduled Tasks in event viewer.
[Event Viewer Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oULcg.png)
[Task options in GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPuif.png)

Comment: May be related to permissions since script is running as the device (system) account and traversing the network. Can you confirm Authenticated Users (more specifically the computer account) have read/execute permissions on the file. *Check both NTFS and share permissions.

Comment: @Qwilson I already check permissions. That script it's inside a folder who is used for another GPOS and works fine.
I have permissions for SYSTEM, Authenticated Users, Domain Admins, Domain Users, Administrators and Users.

Comment: I checked this question (https://serverfault.com/questions/641172/gpo-startup-script-not-being-ran?rq=1) and tried to restart computer with a wired cable connected but nothing happens.

Comment: The screenshot of your task settings shows it is trying to run the task as the 'domain users' group. Pretty sure it needs to run as a user principal and not a group. Since it is a computer startup script you may want to run the task as the SYSTEM principal. This will cause the task to run in the context of the domain computer.